# Group Filters in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

Can we have multiple group filters created in BI Publisher?

I want to have more than 1 group filter i.e for example SAL >5000 & DEPT_ID IN (10,20). Right now I'm able to add only 1 group filter. Will BI Publisher allow me to add multiple group filters??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple group filters.

Write your data model and when you are going to save it,add all the parameters you want to keep in Parameters tab.

See the screenshot below

[image]

In your case,you don't have any parameter,so this you want is only to write the sql query and in where clause to put the conditions.

i.e

where SAL >5000 and DEPT_ID IN (10,20)

Hope,this helps..